# Python - Missing rest_framework module

Tags: python, docker, django-rest-framework

I've created a new project using docker. I've followed this instruction:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/?fbclid=IwAR0TKmDbxyRrIs0PU4IbfQVBI9Tqh8cjnBaXuI5rqGwkV5j2eYrjlAh5qUI

Before creating project, I've added rest_framework to my requirements.txt.
But I've got an error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework'

when I'm trying to add 'rest_framework' to the INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py file.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

and requirements.txt:

```
Django==2.1.7
psycopg2==2.7.7
pytz==2018.9
djangorestframework==3.9.2
```

All content from settings.py file:

```
import os
import rest_framework

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'XXX'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'library.apps.LibraryConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'officemanager.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'officemanager.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I've noticed that pycharm suggest me that:

> "Package requirement djangorestframework==3.9.2 is not satisfied."

How to import or install rest framework to project correctly?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with django, but I can `import rest_framework` just fine after `pip install djangorestframework` is run within a python 3.6 image. What is the settings.py supposed to do in this case? And can you post the contents of that file in your question?

Comment: I've updated my question :)

Comment: Can't reach that site, usually pasting code in external links doesn't work for everyone on SO, just a heads up

Comment: Ok, so question, are you trying to run this in pycharm or in docker? A docker container is not tied to the virtualenv that you may be using in pycharm

Comment: I've pasted settings.py code directly to the question, could you see? hmm I've tried to run docker-compose up in the normal terminal as well and without result.